# Discord.js: How do I catch the case if the input is not a known command?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am trying to catch the case when the user enters a command that is not present, however I don't know exactly where and how to do that.
I have built my discord bot in such a way that it has an eventhandler and a commandhandler.

My eventHandler:

```
function reqEvent(event) {
return require(`../events/${event}`);
}

module.exports = bot => {
bot.on('ready', function() { reqEvent('ready') (bot); });
};
```

The 'ready' event:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { commandHandler } = require('../config.json');

module.exports = client => {
    client.user.setActivity('Diener');
    const commandBase = require(`../handlers/${commandHandler}`);

    const readCommands = (dir) => {
        // TODO: Find a better solution to determine the project folder
        const __dirname = 'C:\\Users\\marce\\Documents\\Discord-Test-Bot';

        // Read out all command files
        const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));

        // Loop through all the files in ./commands
        for (const file of files) {
            // Get the status of 'file' (is it a file or directory?)
            const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));

            // If the 'file' is a directory, call the 'readCommands' function
            // again with the path of the subdirectory
            if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                readCommands(path.join(dir, file));
            }

            // If the 'file' is not the commandHandler itself, get all the
            // commandOptions of that file
            else if (file !== commandHandler) {
                const commandOption = require(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));
                // Call the commandHandler and pass the commandOptions and
                // the client
                commandBase(client, commandOption);
            }
        }
    };

    readCommands('commands');
    console.log(`${client.user.username} is online`);
```

And finally the commandHandler:

```
const { prefix } = require('../config.json');

const validatePermissions = (permissions) => {
    const validPermissions = [
        'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE',
        'KICK_MEMBERS',
        'BAN_MEMBERS',
        'ADMINISTRATOR',
        'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
        'MANAGE_GUILD',
        'ADD_REACTIONS',
        'VIEW_AUDIT_LOG',
        'PRIORITY_SPEAKER',
        'STREAM',
        'VIEW_CHANNEL',
        'SEND_MESSAGES',
        'SEND_TTS_MESSAGES',
        'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
        'EMBED_LINKS',
        'ATTACH_FILES',
        'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',
        'MENTION_EVERYONE',
        'USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS',
        'VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS',
        'CONNECT',
        'SPEAK',
        'MUTE_MEMBERS',
        'DEAFEN_MEMBERS',
        'MOVE_MEMBERS',
        'USE_VAD',
        'CHANGE_NICKNAME',
        'MANAGE_NICKNAMES',
        'MANAGE_ROLES',
        'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS',
        'MANAGE_EMOJIS',
    ];

    for (const permission of permissions) {
        if (!validPermissions.includes(permission)) {
            throw new Error(`Unknown permission node "${permission}"`);
        }
    }
};

module.exports = (client, commandOptions) => {
    let {
        commands,
        aliases,
        expectedArgs = '',
        permissionError = 'You do not have permission to run this command.',
        minArgs = 0,
        maxArgs = null,
        permissions = [],
        requiredRoles = [],
        execute,
    } = commandOptions;

    // TODO: Handle aliases => seperate them into a extra option

    // Ensure the command and aliases are in an array
    if (typeof commands === 'string') {
        commands = [commands];
    }

    console.log(`Registering command "${commands[0]}"`);

    // Ensure the permissions are in an array and are all valid
    if (permissions.length) {
        if (typeof permissions === 'string') {
            permissions = [permissions];
        }

        validatePermissions(permissions);
    }

    // Listen for messages
    client.on('message', (message) => {
        const { member, content, guild } = message;

        if (message.author.bot) return;

        for (const alias of commands) {
            const command = `${prefix}${alias.toLowerCase()}`;

            if (!content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${prefix}`)) return;

            if (content.toLowerCase() != command || !content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${command} `))
               return message.reply('Unknown command!');

            console.log('Geht weiter');
            // A command has been ran

            // Ensure the user has the required permissions
            for (const permission of permissions) {
                if (!member.hasPermission(permission)) {
                    message.reply(permissionError);
                    return;
                }
            }

            // Ensure the user has the required roles
            for (const requiredRole of requiredRoles) {
                const role = guild.roles.cache.find(
                    (r) => r.name === requiredRole,
                );

                if (!role || !member.roles.cache.has(role.id)) {
                    return message.reply(
                        `You must have the "${requiredRole}" role to use this command.`,
                    );
                }
            }

            // Split on any number of spaces
            const args = content.split(/[ ]+/);

            // Remove the command which is the first index
            args.shift();

            // Ensure we have the correct number of arguments
            if (
                args.length < minArgs || (maxArgs !== null && args.length > maxArgs)
            ) {
                return message.reply(
                    `Incorrect syntax! Use ${prefix}${alias} ${expectedArgs}`,
                );
            }

            // Handle the custom command code
            execute(message, args, args.join(' '), client);

            return;
        }
    });
};
```

I have already tried to intercept it by this line (in the commandHandler):

```
if (content.toLowerCase() != command || !content.toLowerCase().startsWith(`${command} `)) 
return message.reply('Unknown command');
```

However, the problem occurred that the error message was sent several times, or even when the command actually exists, because the commandHandler is called by the 'ready' event as many times as there are commands. In other words, if there are a total of 10 commands in my bot, the commandHandler is called 10 times and each time it checks whether the message is a valid command or not.
So how can I intercept this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this command / eventhandler is, that if you have too many commands you will get a warning, because it makes a listener for every command.

Try the command / eventhandler V2 by Codelyon (Search on YouTube)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to list all commands and compare with a foreach loop.
I don't know what file structure you use, but in most of cases is something like this:

```
// Where "command" is the command performed by the
// user and "commands" is an array with all avaliable
// commands (if you have each command in a different
// file you can generate the array with node "fs" package)

var valid = false; //Define a "valid" bool variable with default false value

foreach(cmd in commands){ //If any element of commands is equal to "command" set "valid" to true
    if(command == cmd) valid = true;
}

if(!valid){ // If not valid raply to the user
    message.reply("That's not a valid command!");
}
else{
    // Existing command, do what you want
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I do not know where to place this check. Assuming I have two commands and I enter a command that does not exist, the bot also responds to me twice that this command does not exist, even with this check built in. But it should answer me only once